# How to track web application request origin?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have one web application written in J2EE and want to track each request's origin means **from where this request is made**. Here request origin means **don't want to track from which domain or IP address** this request is made to my application but want to find below categories:

- my application itself
- email(sent by my application)
- social media(any links posted on social media)
- search engine
- others

I have already one solution is like append one request parameter to each link(generated by my application) and track based on that but still I want some smart logic like if I could track request headers or something else...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JAX-WS with SOAP messages you can use the [message handlers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html). It takes to define an `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>` and append it to an `HandlerChain` through the configuration file `handlers.xml`.

With this approach you will be able to "inspect" the incoming request messages ant then to perform some custom field evaluations.